# black screen when running the app - ios

Tags: objective-c, storyboard, xcode6, ios-simulator

in my project i have different storyboard files to support different iPhone sizes, here is the code that handles picking the right storyboard file in AppDelegate:

```
#define kMain5Name @"Main5"
#define kMain4sName @"Main4s"
#define kMain6Name @"Main6"
#define kMain6plusName @"Main6plus"

if (window.frame.size.height == 568){
    UIStoryboard *storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:kMain5Name bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    id rootViewController = [storyBoard instantiateInitialViewController];
    [window setRootViewController:rootViewController];
} else if (window.frame.size.height == 480){
    UIStoryboard *storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:kMain4sName bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    id rootViewController = [storyBoard instantiateInitialViewController];
    [window setRootViewController:rootViewController];
} else if (window.frame.size.height == 667){
    UIStoryboard *storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:kMain6Name bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    id rootViewController = [storyBoard instantiateInitialViewController];
    [window setRootViewController:rootViewController];
} else if (window.frame.size.height == 736){
    UIStoryboard *storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:kMain6plusName bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    id rootViewController = [storyBoard instantiateInitialViewController];
    [window setRootViewController:rootViewController];
}
```

i also have background music. When i run the app it shows a black screen with music playing even on a physical device. i tried resetting the simulator content and settings, cleaning the project and commenting the above code, i also have the main interface set the LaunchImage (.xib) in mt project navigator, but to no avail..
am i doing something wrong? is there another method of supporting different iPhone sizes?